# Geopandas: Get a box that coveres area of a geopandas GeoDataFrame to use it to invert a map

Tags: geopandas

I'm trying to invert a map.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
denmark = world[world.name == 'Denmark']
```

I would like to find out the boundaries of the "denmark" dataframe, to that I can create a box shaped GeoDataFrame that covers all of Denmark.

I'd then intersect that with "denmark" to get a shape of all that is not denmark, which I can later use to cover parts of a map I don't want to show.

I tried looking through the GeoDataFrame to create this box manually, but that doesn't work well.

```
cords = [c3
         for c in mapping(denmark['geometry'])['features']
         for c2 in c['geometry']['coordinates']
         for c3 in c2
        ]


xcords = [x[0] for x in cords if isinstance(x[0], float)]
ycords = [y[1] for y in cords if isinstance(y[1], float)]

w3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    [Polygon([[max(xcords), max(ycords)],
         [max(xcords), min(ycords)],
         [min(xcords), min(ycords)],
         [min(xcords), max(ycords)]
         ])],
    columns = ['geometry'],
    geometry='geometry')
```

Is there an easy, quick way to get this box?
Or is there a way tp invert a GeoDataFrame?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A GeoDataFrame has the [`total_bounds`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds) attribute, which returns the minx, miny, maxx, maxy of all geometries (the min/max of the `bounds` of all geometries).
And to create a Polygon of this, you can then pass those values to the [`shapely.geometry.box`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box) function:

```
>>> denmark.total_bounds                                                      
array([ 8.08997684, 54.80001455, 12.69000614, 57.73001659])

>>> from shapely.geometry import box

>>> box(*denmark.total_bounds)                                 
<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f06be3e7668>

>>> print(box(*denmark.total_bounds))                                          
POLYGON ((12.6900061377556 54.80001455343792, 12.6900061377556 57.73001658795485, 8.089976840862221 57.73001658795485, 8.089976840862221 54.80001455343792, 12.6900061377556 54.80001455343792))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a GeoDataFrame has a property "total_bounds"

So it's

```
denmark.total_bounds
```

which returns

```
array([ 8.08997684, 54.80001455, 12.69000614, 57.73001659])
```